# Is there a word for 'saying what others are thinking'?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word for 'saying what others are thinking' ? I'm just looking for a shorter way of expressing it, ideally in a word or very short phrase. I've searched online but am having difficulty finding out, so am guessing there may not be one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Anticipating' may work on occasion.

Comment: Are you asking about the “Saying the quiet part out loud.” behavior or just the “I think I can speak for all of us when I say...” thing?

Comment: I know somebody who uses "I'm only saying what others are thinking" as a way to try to claim that other people agree with the racist things that they just said. Is that the sort of use you had in mind? Unclear if you have a positive or negative situation in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Preemptive speaking, and various combinations using ‘preemptive’, comes to mind.

Comment: This would be improved with some supporting examples of the use of the term.

Comment: [Pre-empt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preempt) means to stop other people from doing something (senses 2 and 5 there), more than it means to do what everybody wants to do.